# how i can save data in database column from custom newsletter field in Magento 2?

Tags: magento2

```
<?php

namespace Vendor\Module\Plugin\Newsletter;

use Magento\Framework\App\Request\Http;

class Subscriber {
  protected $request;

  public function __construct(
    Http $request
  ) {
    $this->request = $request;
  }

  public function aroundSubscribe($subject, \Closure $proceed, $email) {
    if ($this->request->isPost() && $this->request->getPost('subscriber_name')) {
      $firstname = $this->getRequest->getPost('subscriber_name');
      print_r($firstname);
      $subject->setCFirstname($firstname);
      $result = $proceed($email);

      try {
        $subject->save();
      }catch (\Exception $e) {
        throw new \Exception($e->getMessage());
      }
    }

    return $result;
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you trying to save a customer attribute? And can you show the code in the di.xml for the plugin too?

Comment: Is Custom newsletter field in Custom table or in product table ? Please elaborate.

Comment: @BornCoder Custom newsletter field

Comment: @AlanZavagli  di.xml        <?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="../../../../../lib/internal/Magento/Framework/ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
  <type name="Magento\Newsletter\Model\Subscriber">
    <plugin name="vendor_module_newsletter_model_subscriber" type="Vendor\Module\Plugin\Newsletter\Subscriber"/>
  </type>
</config>

Comment: Please check answer here - https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/344887/how-i-can-save-the-data-from-custom-newsletter-to-database/

Comment: @ZealousWeb thank you