# how i can save the data from custom newsletter to database

Tags: magento2

I want to save custom newsletter field in databse but only email value is showing in database after subscribe the newsletter .subscriber_name is showing null value
This is my question [How to save input value to database from custom newsletter magento2](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/344840/how-to-save-input-value-to-database-from-custom-newsletter-magento2) Help me please

Comment: In which table you are try to save that value? And does those fields created into the table?

Comment: @DhirenVasoya field created in table but value showing null after susbscribe newsletter help me please

Comment: @DhirenVasoya https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/344840/how-to-save-input-value-to-database-from-custom-newsletter-magento2 please see my code and help me please

Comment: check the answer. I am sharing with you I wrote the module.https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/344840/how-to-save-input-value-to-database-from-custom-newsletter-magento2/344893#344893

Comment: @Devidas thank you so much bro its work for me

Comment: Welcome........

Comment: @Devidas hey bro i am  getting same issu null value in  database table after using SMTP server smtp server work properly but i getting same issu null value in my database  name table

Comment: i used your module but i getting null value why i dont know

Comment: @Devidas Also i am not getting any error in exception.log

Comment: print post data and check what value you getting

Comment: i getting same issu null value in my custom table

Comment: print_r($this->request->getPost()); in plugin file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please use below event to save your custom field data.

> Step 1: Please create file events.xml in path Vendor/Module/etc/

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:Event/etc/events.xsd">
    <event name="newsletter_subscriber_save_before">
        <observer name="newsletter_subscriber_save_before" instance="Vendor\Module\Observer\newsletterSubscriberSave" />
    </event>
</config>
```

> Step 2: Please create file newsletterSubscriberSave.php under path
> Vendor/Module/Observer/

```
<?php
namespace Vendor\Module\Observer;

use \Magento\Framework\Event\Observer;
use \Magento\Framework\Event\ObserverInterface;

class newsletterSubscriberSave implements ObserverInterface
{
    protected $_request;

    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Framework\App\RequestInterface $request
    ) {
        $this->_request = $request;
    }

    public function execute(Observer $observer)
    {
        $subscriber = $observer->getEvent()->getSubscriber();
        $params = $this->_request->getParams();

        if(isset($params['subscriber_name'])) {
            $name = $params['subscriber_name'];
            $subscriber->setSubscriberName($name);
        }

        return $this;
    }
}
```

With the use of above code you can save custom field value. It will work for you.

**Cheers!**

Comment: Hey Thanks its work  for me